# How to fix error number: 8114 'Procedure or function has too many arguments specified' in c# windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I have to create procedure in *SQLServer* like,

```
create procedure LeaveMasterProcdure(
@code nvarchar(20),
@type nvarchar(20),
@condition nvarchar(1000),
@leavedays nvarchar(50)
)
As
DECLARE @Max INT
        , @id varchar(50)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM LeaveMaster)
BEGIN
        SET @id = 'L001'                     
        INSERT INTO dbo.LeaveMaster(id,code,type,conditions,No_ofleaves)
        VALUES(@id,@code,@type,@condition,@leavedays)         
END
ELSE
BEGIN
        SELECT @Max = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),id), 2,   10)) FROM LeaveMaster
        SET @id = 'L' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @Max + 1), 5)
        INSERT INTO dbo.LeaveMaster(id,code,type,conditions,No_ofleaves)
        VALUES(@id,@code,@type,@condition,@leavedays)    
        END
```

Also I insert value by procedure is insert in *SqlManagementStudio*

But when I'm trying to insert a procedure by program I got **Procedure or function has too many arguments specified** exception. This code:

```
                SqlCommand AddLeave = con.CreateCommand();

                SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                SqlParameter code = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                SqlParameter type = new SqlParameter("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                SqlParameter conditions = new SqlParameter("@conditions", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                SqlParameter No_ofleaves = new SqlParameter("@No_ofleaves", SqlDbType.VarChar);

                AddLeave.Parameters.Add(id);
                AddLeave.Parameters.Add(code);
                AddLeave.Parameters.Add(type);
                AddLeave.Parameters.Add(conditions);
                AddLeave.Parameters.Add(No_ofleaves);

                SqlCommand ccc = new SqlCommand("select type from LeaveMaster", con);

                SqlDataReader r1 = ccc.ExecuteReader();
                while (r1.Read())
                {
                    s1 = r1["type"].ToString();
                }
                if (s1 == null)
                    id.Value = " ";
                else if (s1 != null)
                    id.Value = s1.ToString();
                r1.Close();


                code.Value = textBox_Leave_Code.Text;
                type.Value = textBox_Leave_Type.Text;
                conditions.Value = textBox_Conditions.Text;
                No_ofleaves.Value = textBox_total_leave.Text;

                AddLeave.Connection = con;

                AddLeave.CommandText = "LeaveMasterProcdure @id,@code,@type,@conditions,@No_ofleaves";


                try
                {
                    AddLeave.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("added");
                }
                catch (Exception vv)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(vv.ToString());
                }
```

I don't know how to fix it. Please help me...

Comment: You have 4 parameters in your precedure and 5 in your code. And they should be named equal.

Comment: remove this line `SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar);` and rename `@No_ofleaves` to `@leavedays`

Comment: @tinka is not work same exception

Comment: please replace each places `No_ofleaves` to `leavedays`

Comment: Looking at your procedure create command - it has no id parameter. Try removing "@id," from the AddLeave.CommandText line.

Comment: @PaulF actually You right.Happy for your help :)

Comment: @tinka Its work happy for your help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `@id` parameter is not in the procedure.
2. `@conditions` in the code doesn't match `@condition` in the procedure.
3. `@No_ofleaves` doesn't match `@leavedays` in the procedure.

Here's an easy way to make these easier to catch. Copy the parameter list from the stored procedure into your C# code and comment it out. Now you've got them both in one place and you don't have to switch back and forth. When you're done delete the comments.

I usually copy and paste parameter names from my SQL because it eliminates the possibility of typos.

```
//@code nvarchar(20),
//@type nvarchar(20),
//@condition nvarchar(1000),
//@leavedays nvarchar(50)

SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar);
SqlParameter code = new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar);
SqlParameter type = new SqlParameter("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar);
SqlParameter conditions = new SqlParameter("@conditions", SqlDbType.VarChar);
SqlParameter No_ofleaves = new SqlParameter("@No_ofleaves", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```